# Dart : parse date timezone gives UnimplementedError

Tags: date, dart, flutter, timezone, date-formatting

I need to **parse a date** in the following format in my **Flutter** application (come from JSON) :

**2019-05-17T15:03:22.472+0000**

According to [the documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html), I have to use `Z` to get the time zone (last 5 characters in RFC 822 format), so I use the following :

```
new DateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:s.SZ").parseStrict(json['startDate']);
```

But it fails with error :

> FormatException: Characters remaining after date parsing in
>   2019-05-17T15:03:22.472+0000

Here is another test :

```
/// THIS WORKS
try {
    print(new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(DateTime.now()));
} catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
}

/// THIS RETURNS `UnimplementedError` (as soon as I use a 'Z' or 'z') somewhere
try {
    print(new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(DateTime.now()));
} catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
}
```

Is `Z` implemented ?

Comment: Have you found a way to format a date with "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" like pattern? Any third party solutions?

Comment: As suggested in the accepted answer I used `DateTime.parse` to parse the date, then `DateFormat` to display it in my own format, i.e. `DateFormat(yourNewFormat).format(DateTime.parse(yourDateAsString))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need the result to be like "2019-10-04T12:38:14+0300" with time zone encoded. This code `DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(DateTime.now())` results in `Unimplemented` exception. So I wonder is there any way to achieve that in Flutter?

Comment: Oh it's about formatting, not parsing, sorry misunderstood your question. So indeed `DateFormat` does not support time zone (and will not until Dart `DateTime` will have time zone information). For now you can try another package like [time_machine](https://pub.dev/packages/time_machine) which seem to support time zones. Or maybe you can append the time zone manually using [timeZoneOffset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/timeZoneOffset.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`DateFormat` class docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html):

> DateFormat is for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner.

You're not asking to parse a locale-sensitive date string but rather an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string, so thus you should not use the `DateFormat` class.

Instead, use the [`DateTime.parse` method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html), which supports the format you described, per its docs:

> Examples of accepted strings:
>
> - ...
> - "2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500": Same as "2002-02-27T19:00:00Z"

Answer (score 11):

Sadly `z` and `v` patterns are not implemented.

Those won't be implemented until Dart DateTime's have time zone information

More info on this issue https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/19

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's a shame it has not been fixed since 2015, without any mention in the documentation.

Comment: I remove z at the end and format/parse still works, but might not correct in some cases

Answer (score 2):

You can use this format

```
print(new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(DateTime.now()));
```

It worked for me.