# How to format this date 2019-04-05T14:00:51.000Z in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
var df = new DateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
```

var date = df.parse(course.date);
      String rt = df.format(date);

Comment: give me formatted exception when make print to date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The date you are trying to format `2019-04-05T14:00:51.000Z` is in UTC format (since it ends with Z) and it also has `T` in the middle of the `date` which is nothing but a separator to differentiate between `date` and `time`.

The `DateFormat` class is very static and has limitations when it comes to dates like above. So we first have to manipulate the given date to only consider the `date` and `time` parts of the input, like below:

```
var str = "2019-04-05T14:00:51.000Z";
var newStr = str.substring(0,10) + ' ' + str.substring(11,23);
print(newStr);  // 2019-04-05 14:00:51.000
```

Note that, the string need to be in acceptable format before we parse them. Hence we need to also leave out `Z` which is same as `2019-04-05T14:00:51.000`. More reference about this point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56192195).

Then, we need to convert the string into `DateTime` object and then pass this object to `DateFormat's` format method, as below:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(newStr);
print(DateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(dt));
```

This gives us : `Fri, 5 Apr 2019 14:00:51` in the format we wanted.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

That code is very helpful to convert web time into dart `2023-03-16T03:28:51.000000Z`:

```
static String timeFormate(var time) {
  DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse(time.toString());

  return DateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(dt1);
}
```

That code return the string type data